# Parse JSON response in android "response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Tags: java, android, json

I've seen there are quite a few questions around, but I think I am missing a detail that I couldn't find out.

The String I am getting as a response is included in the following error:

```
12-28 10:25:14.402: W/System.err(2133): org.json.JSONException: Value
{"status":"ok","userTier":"developer","total":1722082,"startIndex":1,"pageSize":5,"currentPage":1,"pages":344417,"orderBy":"newest",
"results":[{"webTitle":"AirAsia flight loses contact with air traffic control between Indonesia and Singapore","webPublicationDate":"2014-12-28T09:06:55Z","sectionName":"World news","sectionId":"world","id":"world\/live\/2014\/dec\/28\/airasia-flight-loses-contact-with-air-traffic-control-on-route-from-indonesia-to-singapore","webUrl":"
...  at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

My code is

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);// result is the sting response presented above
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("response");
```

Comment: I can't find response key

Comment: You have an error on "response" key.
Where is it ?!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` key is JSONObject, you need to use `getJSONObject` instead current method.

Answer (score 1):

The only JSONArray I see is the results key. You have to use the results key or you need the getJSONObject()-Method, as gio mentioned above.